# How can I delete duplicates with Abs?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I have this list with some duplicate elements and I want to delete duplicate ones.

```
mylist = {ConditionalExpression[1, -1 <= x <= 0], 
   ConditionalExpression[-x, x <= -1], 
   ConditionalExpression[-x, x <= -1], 
   ConditionalExpression[Abs[x], x <= -1]};
```

Now I tried to delete duplicate elements with this.

```
DeleteDuplicates[mylist]
```

[image: Code output]

This doesn't work. I expected that two of these three elements `{ConditionalExpression[-x, x <= -1],  ConditionalExpression[-x, x <= -1],  ConditionalExpression[Abs[x], x <= -1]}` should be deleted.

Then I thought probably that was due to Mathematica thinking that `x` is complex, so I added the assumption that x is real, but this didn't work either.

```
Assuming[x \[Element] Reals, DeleteDuplicates[mylist]]
```

[image: results from assumptions code; no difference in result]

How can I delete duplicate elements so the three elements above are considered duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DeleteDuplicates[Refine[mylist, Assumptions -> x ∈ Reals]]
```

gives what you want

> [image: res]

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
DeleteDuplicates[Refine[Map[LogicalExpand, mylist], Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]]
```

[image]

Comment: This one is a bit longer than bmf's answer. I wonder if there is any case this works but bmf's answer or vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you do want to keep one of the equivalent `ConditionalExpression`s

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[mylist, Refine[#, #[[2]]] &]
```

> {ConditionalExpression[1, -1 <= x <= 0], ConditionalExpression[-x, x <= -1]}

Comment: I think this would consider `{ConditionalExpression[1 - x, 0 <= x <= 1/2], 
 ConditionalExpression[1 - x, x <= 1/2]}` duplicates while they aren't.